# How can I compare similarities between faces after extracting face landmarks from react-native-face-detection?

Tags: react-native, face-recognition

I am using react native to build android app. I want the app to be able to run fully offline. Now, I am using react-native-face-detection. I am detecting the face and then storing the landmarks in encrypted Storage along with username and code. But, at the time of login how can I compare if the live user is one of the registered user?
this my data format on detecting a face.

```json
{
    "rightEyeOpenProbability": null,
    "smilingProbability": null,
    "landmarks": [
        {
            "type": 0,
            "position": [
                1219.4776611328125,
                2416.17724609375
            ]
        },
        {
            "type": 11,
            "position": [
                1495.6180419921875,
                2286.441162109375
            ]
        },
        {
            "type": 5,
            "position": [
                974.8775634765625,
                2327.33056640625
            ]
        },
        {
            "type": 10,
            "position": [
                1513.05078125,
                1610.06787109375
            ]
        },
        {
            "type": 4,
            "position": [
                864.3452758789062,
                1674.1524658203125
            ]
        },
        {
            "type": 9,
            "position": [
                1894.5218505859375,
                1520.0875244140625
            ]
        },
        {
            "type": 3,
            "position": [
                562.1290283203125,
                1753.53759765625
            ]
        },
        {
            "type": 7,
            "position": [
                1641.6800537109375,
                2005.3045654296875
            ]
        },
        {
            "type": 1,
            "position": [
                783.49365234375,
                2085.6513671875
            ]
        },
        {
            "type": 6,
            "position": [
                1179.479248046875,
                2028.662109375
            ]
        }
    ],
    "headEulerAngleX": -12.914505958557129,
    "headEulerAngleY": -1.8928173780441284,
    "trackingId": null,
    "headEulerAngleZ": 4.549933433532715,
    "faceContours": [],
    "leftEyeOpenProbability": null,
    "boundingBox": [
        385,
        925,
        2048,
        2614
    ]
}
```

This is my Login.js Code:-

```js
import React, {useState, useEffect} from 'react';
import {View, Text, Button} from 'react-native';
import {SafeAreaView} from 'react-native-safe-area-context';
import EncryptedStorage from 'react-native-encrypted-storage';
import FaceDetection, {
  FaceDetectorContourMode,
  FaceDetectorLandmarkMode,
} from 'react-native-face-detection';
import {launchCamera} from 'react-native-image-picker';

const Login = () => {
  const [registeredUsers, setRegisteredUsers] = useState([]);
  const [liveUser, setLiveUser] = useState();
  const [capturedImageUri, setCapturedImageUri] = useState(null);
  // Your function to calculate similarity
  function calculateMean(coords) {
    const sum = coords.reduce(
      (acc, [x, y]) => {
        acc.x += x;
        acc.y += y;
        return acc;
      },
      {x: 0, y: 0},
    );
    const mean = {
      x: sum.x / coords.length,
      y: sum.y / coords.length,
    };
    return mean;
  }

  // Center the landmarks
  function centerLandmarks(coords, mean) {
    return coords.map(([x, y]) => [x - mean.x, y - mean.y]);
  }

  // Scale the landmarks
  function scaleLandmarks(coords) {
    const sumOfSquares = coords.reduce(
      (acc, [x, y]) => {
        acc.x += x ** 2;
        acc.y += y ** 2;
        return acc;
      },
      {x: 0, y: 0},
    );

    const scale = 1 / Math.sqrt(sumOfSquares.x + sumOfSquares.y);

    return coords.map(([x, y]) => [x * scale, y * scale]);
  }

  // Calculate the root mean squared difference
  function calculateRMSD(coords1, coords2) {
    const sumOfSquaredDifferences = coords1.reduce((acc, [x1, y1], i) => {
      const x2 = coords2[i][0];
      const y2 = coords2[i][1];
      const squaredDistance = Math.pow(x1 - x2, 2) + Math.pow(y1 - y2, 2);
      return acc + squaredDistance;
    }, 0);

    const similarityScore = Math.sqrt(sumOfSquaredDifferences / coords1.length);
    return similarityScore;
  }

  // Calculate the Procrustes similarity score
  function calculateProcrustesSimilarity(coords1, coords2) {
    const mean1 = calculateMean(coords1);
    const mean2 = calculateMean(coords2);

    const centeredCoords1 = centerLandmarks(coords1, mean1);
    const centeredCoords2 = centerLandmarks(coords2, mean2);

    const scaledCoords1 = scaleLandmarks(centeredCoords1);
    const scaledCoords2 = scaleLandmarks(centeredCoords2);

    const similarityScore = calculateRMSD(scaledCoords1, scaledCoords2);
    return similarityScore;
  }

  const loadRegisteredUsers = async () => {
    try {
      const userData = await EncryptedStorage.getItem('registeredUsers');
      if (userData) {
        const allUsers = JSON.parse(userData);
        setRegisteredUsers(allUsers);
      }
      return [];
    } catch (error) {
      console.error('Error loading registered users:', error);
      return [];
    }
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    loadRegisteredUsers();
  }, []);

  const handleLogin = () => {
    const options = {
      mediaType: 'photo',
    };

    launchCamera(options, async response => {
      if (response.didCancel) {
        console.log('User cancelled image picker');
      } else if (response.error) {
        console.log('ImagePicker Error: ', response.error);
      } else {
        // Read the image file and convert it to base64
        try {
          setCapturedImageUri(response.assets[0].uri);
          extractFaceLandmarks(response.assets[0].uri).then(() => {
            // Compare live user's landmarks with registered users
            if (liveUser && liveUser.landmarks && registeredUsers.length > 0) {
              const liveUserCoords = liveUser.landmarks.map(
                landmark => landmark.position,
              );
              for (const user of registeredUsers) {
                const userCoords = user.landmarks.map(
                  landmark => landmark.position,
                );
                const similarityScore =
                  calculateProcrustesSimilarity(liveUserCoords, userCoords) *
                  100;
                if (similarityScore<=6) {
                  // Adjust the threshold as needed
                  console.log('User recognized:', recognizedUser);
                  return;
                }
              }
            }
            console.log('User not recognized');
          });
        } catch (error) {
          console.error('Error reading image file:', error);
        }
      }
    });
  };
  async function extractFaceLandmarks(imagePath) {
    const options = {
      contourMode: FaceDetectorContourMode.ALL,
      landmarkMode: FaceDetectorLandmarkMode.ALL,
    };
    const faces = await FaceDetection.processImage(imagePath, options);
    console.log(faces);
    if (faces) {
      // Store user information and landmarks
      const userInformation = {
        landmarks: faces[0].landmarks,
      };
      setLiveUser(userInformation);
    } else {
      return setRegistrationResult('Failed to extract facial landmarks.');
    }
  }

  return (
    <SafeAreaView>
      <View>
        <Button title="Login" onPress={handleLogin} />
      </View>
    </SafeAreaView>
  );
};

export default Login;
```

The result is not meeting my requirements as it's not that accurate.